Membership verification API
Here is my code to check if the Google account trying to connect is subscribed or not to a specific YouTube channel and I wanted to use the same logic for membership but I didn't find anything.
How can I adapt the following code to test whether someone is a member or not?
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

if (!isset($_SESSION['access_token'])) {
    header('Location: login.html');
    exit();
}

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);

$youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);
$oauth2 = new Google_Service_Oauth2($client);
$userInfo = $oauth2->userinfo->get();
$userEmail = $userInfo->email;

try {
    $subscriptionsResponse = $youtube->subscriptions->listSubscriptions('snippet', ['mine' => true]);

    $isSubscribed = false;
    foreach ($subscriptionsResponse->getItems() as $subscription) {
        if ($subscription->getSnippet()->getResourceId()->getChannelId() == 'UCDGmZYT5QfvfEXgzaEAYNpg') {
            $isSubscribed = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if ($isSubscribed) {
        $_SESSION['user_email'] = $userEmail;
        header('Location: form.html');
        exit();
    } else {
        echo 'Vous devez être abonné à notre chaîne YouTube pour accéder au formulaire.';
        exit();
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Erreur lors de la récupération des abonnements : ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit();
}
?>


Cannot you do the other way around, that is list the channel ids of the members (with something like YouTube Data API v3 Members: list endpoint) and use YouTube API to verify that they are connected with these channel ids?
